# jQuery - creating a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function

I'm sorry for the general title, but I don't realy know how to call it.

Here is my code, that I want to reduce:

```
    $('.ShowDialogIcon').click(function() {
        $('.show_dialog').slideDown('fast');
        return false;
    });

    $('.ShowDialogIcon2').click(function() {
        $('.show_dialog2').slideDown('fast');
        return false;
    });

    $('.ShowDialogIcon3').click(function() {
        $('.show_dialog3').slideDown('fast');
        return false;
    });

    $('.ShowDialogIcon4').click(function() {
        $('.show_dialog4').slideDown('fast');
        return false;
    });
```

Now I see, that this is a bit unefective, what I would like to do is:

```
$('.ShowDialogIcon').showDialog('.showDialog');
$('.ShowDialogIcon2').showDialog('.showDialog2');
$('.ShowDialogIcon4').showDialog('.showDialog3');
$('.ShowDialogIcon4').showDialog('.showDialog4');
```

And what I've come up with is:

```
jQuery.fn.showDialog = function(cls) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(cls).show('fast');
    });
}
```

And it doesn't work, can anyone help please?

Thanks, Mike.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What do you see? What errors are reported?

Comment: You're using two different classes in your examples.  `.show_dialog2` in the current code and `.showDialog2` in the desired code.  Intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting click event on the wrong element.

### The correct jQuery plugin

This is an equivalent to your functionality:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    showDialog: function(cls) {
        this.click(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            $(cls).slideDown("fast");
        });
    }
});
```

To stop event bubbling it's better to use `preventDefault` function on the event itself than returning false. This way you can safely avoid browsers' particularities.

Comment: You're setting `jQuery.fn.extend` to an object, rather than calling it on the object...

Comment: @sberry2A: Thanks. My thoughts exactly. ;)

Comment: Apart from the performance benefit of `this` vs `$(this)`, this should be equivalent to the code above, so this probably isn't the solution, but it's much nicer code!

Comment: This one looks good, but when I use it like: $('.ShowDialogIcon').showDialog('.showDialog'); It stops the link, but nothing slides down =/

Comment: @Mike See Stephen's comment above.

Comment: @lonesomeday: They're not equivalent. `$(this)` makes a clone object of `this` when it's already a jQuery object. So it's not completely the same.

Comment: @Robert "functionally equivalent" then. It makes no difference here.

Comment: @Mike: You're probably mistyping your classes because sometimes you're using underscores and lower casing and sometimes you don't. If the one you've written doesn't work, you should rather try: `$('.ShowDialogIcon').showDialog('.show_dialog')`

Comment: @lonesomeday: That's true. I can agree on that. Functionally equivalent. But slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up a jQuery plugin to do this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.showDialog = function(cls) {
        this.click(function() {
            $(cls).show('fast');
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

$("#foo").showDialog(".bar");
```

See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for how to author a plugin.

Comment: @Robert: Good point, but easier to do it now in case I decide to add some private variables later.

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach to this situation is first give a class that all dialog icons share and add an attribute to the dialog icon that points to the dialog that you want to show. For instance:

```
<a href="#show_dialog1" class="ShowDialogIcon">Show first</a> //href points to the dialog that will slide
<a href="#show_dialog2" class="ShowDialogIcon">Show first</a>  

$(".ShowDialogIcon").click(function(){
    //use the href attribute
    var dialog = $(this).attr("href").replace("#",".");  
    $(dialog).slideDown("fast");  //slidedown
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: i'm guessing you don't like that much then.